# MySQL while for a date loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I looking to run a mysql query and have the number of matching lines for a series of dates be added to an array. To better illustrate this, I have a database with dates, a clients phone number and info for a particular call. I need the run a query that looks and each day for the past thirty days and put the total number of calls for that client on that day and adds it to an array. So if my client had 20 calls today, 15 yesterday, and 10 the day before continuing for 30 day, I need an array that looks like this [20, 15, 10 ...].

I have this so far but can't figure out how to make it repeat for each day and add it to an array.

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db WHERE inbound='$client' AND calldate=$date(*this may need to go)"
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY calldate` to resolve the count by call date:

```
SELECT calldate, COUNT(*) FROM db
  WHERE inbound='$client'
  GROUP BY calldate ORDER BY calldate DESC
```

I am adding `calldate` to the query for your safety. Imagine the client did not call yesterday, then you don't want to skip that day. Make sure to check the `calldate` from within your php code.

EDIT:

Here is a blog post for you that shows an example of how to loop through a result set in php:
http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2012/07/14/phpmysql-query/

Comment: How do I get the array with the data in it?

Comment: That worked great for showing all the days with call. My hang up now is that I need the days with no calls (or entries for that day) to show as well. So if I had no calls yesterday and therefor no entry under that date, how would I be able to show a '0' for that day. Is there a way to do the query for each day and show the results for each day regardless of whether there is calls?

Comment: Yes, but you can also compare `calldate` to the expected date in your loop, and for each day the record is not the expected date, show '0'.

Comment: Sorry a little on the new side of php here. I have this right now, how would I incorporate what you said above into it?        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $data = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
           $data[] = $row[0];
        }